# Text Classification and VIF

Tags: python, nlp

Does VIF matter when it comes to dealing with Text Classification. I have a large dataset, after tokenizing the text, I have 400 columns of stemmed words. After running tests for VIF, I noticed that most variable's VIF were less than 5. The remaining VIF's fluctuated between 6-37, should I be removing these variables?

Comment: What is VIF and how is it calculated?

Comment: VIF is used to measure multicollinearity amongst variables. In python
vif = [variance_inflation_factor(X_test.values, i ) for i in range(len(X_test.columns))]